# Safe to Disconnect during RDC Logoff

Tags: windows, windows-10, rdc

I'm on a windows server (10 I believe) that I use via RDC. I usually sign out, but this takes at least 5-10 minutes. It's always stuck on the blue screen "Please Wait for the User Profile Service." So far, I've always waited, but it's quite annoying.

What happens if I disconnect (via blue bar's "x") during this blue screen wait period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logoff process continues on the server, a bit like turning off the screen on your computer while shutting down.